# How do I install a replacement database file?

Tags: ios, database, file, caching, sqlite

How do I clear out old databases in sqlite3? (version 3.7.12)

I am building an iOS (Xcode) app using sqlite3.

I deleted the dbase file (in `/Users/xx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/nnn/Documents`). I destroyed the copy in the xcode navigation panel. I trashed the copy in the project bundle. And I removed its reference in Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources.

As a test, I did not try to put in a new db file. Only the source code remains `[[SQFXDB alloc] initWithSQFXDBFilename:@"sqfx_v4b"];`.

And build succeeds. And Run succeeds. And the data is still there in the simulator. And a new database file has been created in the `../Documents` dir. All the original data is there.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Delete the app from simulator. Do a clean build and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Delete app from simulator/Reset Contents and Settings for simulator  - run from XCode

Comment: There is no need to reset the simulator. Deleting the app is enough (at least with regard to the simulator).